# Wordpress - rewrite /keyword1+keyword2.html to search page | .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am facing trouble redirecting the keywords to search page in a wordpress  4.4 setup. What I am trying achieve is to rewrite/redirect

*www.site.com/**search+keyword.html*** to *www.site.com/**?s=search+keyword&submit=Search***

I have tried every solution found in google but none works with this version.

.htaccess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.html$ ./?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I can search wordpress using: *http://localhost/wordpress/search/keyword*, but I am unable to change the search url.
*What I need is to fire a search whenever there is a keyword followed by a* **.html** *in the url*. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping your rules around:

The catch all  `RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]`

will stop it from ever hitting your rule

```
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.html$ ./?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

Moving your rule above the standard WP rules should allow yours to work as expected.

Comment: Yes i have tried that, but still wp is not even willing to consider any apart from ?s= or /search/ as the search urls